# How to use search multiple queries together using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, search

```
await User.find({ username: new RegExp(keyword,  'i')}).select('-password')
        .then((profile)=>{
            if(!profile){
                res.json({
                    status: false,
                    message: 'No profiles found'
                })
```

This is for a single search. I want to search for the username, organization, and full_name together. How it possible?

```
await User.find({ username: new RegExp(keyword,  'i') full_name: new RegExp(keyword,  'i'), organisation: new RegExp(keyword,  'i')}).select('-password')
```

This code is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mongoose `$or` to search across fields.

```
User.find({ 
  $or: [
    { username: new RegExp(keyword,  'i') }, 
    { organization: new RegExp(keyword,  'i') }, 
    { full_name: new RegExp(keyword,  'i') }
  ]
})
```

It searches the keyword in the `username`, `organization`, `full_name` fields in each document.